# I'm not getting any outputs for some reason after replacing the javascript functions with imported python functions

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, calculator

index.html :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Advanced Calculator</title>
    <script src="functions.py" defer></script>
    <script src="main.py" defer></script>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calculator-grid">
        <div class="output">
          <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand">xyz</div>
          <div data-current-operand class="current-operand">abc</div>
        </div>
        <button data-all-clear class="span-two">AC</button>
        <button data-delete>DEL</button>
        <button data-operation>÷</button>
        <button data-operation>//</button>
        <button data-operation>rad</button>
        <button data-operation>deg</button>
        <button data-operation>log</button>
        <button data-number>1</button>
        <button data-number>2</button>
        <button data-number>3</button>
        <button data-operation>*</button>
        <button data-operation>**</button>
        <button data-operation>sin</button>
        <button data-operation>cos</button>
        <button data-operation>tan</button>
        <button data-number>4</button>
        <button data-number>5</button>
        <button data-number>6</button>
        <button data-operation>+</button>
        <button data-operation>!</button>
        <button data-operation>cosec</button>
        <button data-operation>sec</button>
        <button data-operation>cot</button>
        <button data-number>7</button>
        <button data-number>8</button>
        <button data-number>9</button>
        <button data-operation>-</button>
        <button data-operation>√</button>
        <button data-operation>ceil</button>
        <button data-operation>floor</button>
        <button data-operation class="span-twoV">rem</button>
        <button data-number>.</button>
        <button data-number>0</button>
        <button data-equals class="span-two">=</button>
        <button data-operation>3√</button>
        <button data-operation class="span-two">||</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css :

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Gotham Rounded, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}


body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, lightblue, rgb(0, 247, 255), blue);
}

.calculator-grid {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 100px);
    grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
}
  
  .calculator-grid > button {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid white;
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}
  
  .calculator-grid > button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(14, 221, 187, 0.9);
}

  .span-two {
    grid-column: span 2;
}
  .span-twoV {
    grid-row: span 2;
}
  .output {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}
  
  .output .previous-operand {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}
  
  .output .current-operand {
    color: white;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

  .output input {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
```

script.js :

```
import { add, subt, multi, divi, power, floDivi, remDivi, log, sqrt, cbrt, rad, deg, sin, cos, tan, cosec, sec, cot, ceil, floor, abso, facto } from functions.py;
class Calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
    this.clear()
  }

  clear() {
    this.currentOperand = ''
    this.previousOperand = ''
    this.operation = undefined
  }

  delete() {
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0, -1)
  }

  appendNumber(number) {
    if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()
  }

  chooseOperation(operation) {
    if (this.currentOperand === '') return
    if (this.previousOperand !== '') {
      this.compute()
    }
    this.operation = operation
    this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand
    this.currentOperand = ''
  }

  compute() {
    let computation
    const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand)
    const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand)
    if (isNaN(prev) || isNaN(current)) return
    switch (this.operation) {
      case '+':
        computation = add(prev, current)
        break
      case '-':
        computation = subt(prev, current)
        break
      case '*':
        computation = multi(prev, current)
        break
      case '÷':
        computation = divi(prev, current)
        break
      case '//':
        computation = floDivi(prev, current)
          break
      case '**':
        computation = power(prev, current)
          break
      case '!':
        computation = facto(prev)
          break
      case '√':
        computation = sqrt(prev)
          break
      case '3√':
        computation = cbrt(prev)
          break
      case 'rad':
        computation = rad(prev)
          break
      case 'deg':
        computation = deg(prev)
          break
      case 'sin':
        computation = sin(prev)
          break
      case 'cos':
        computation = cos(prev)
          break
      case 'tan':
        computation = tan(prev)
          break
      case 'cosec':
        computation = cosec(prev)
          break
      case 'sec':
        computation = sec(prev)
          break
      case 'cot':
        computation = cot(prev)
          break
      case 'ceil':
        computation = ceil(prev)
          break
      case 'floor':
        computation = floor(prev)
          break
      case '||':
        computation = abso(prev)
          break
      case 'rem':
        computation = remDivi(prev, current)
          break
      case 'log':
        computation = log(prev)
          break
        default:
        return
    }
    this.currentOperand = computation
    this.operation = undefined
    this.previousOperand = ''
  }

  getDisplayNumber(number) {
    const stringNumber = number.toString()
    const integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split('.')[0])
    const decimalDigits = stringNumber.split('.')[1]
    let integerDisplay
    if (isNaN(integerDigits)) {
      integerDisplay = ''
    } else {
      integerDisplay = integerDigits.toLocaleString('en', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 })
    }
    if (decimalDigits != null) {
      return `${integerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`
    } else {
      return integerDisplay
    }
  }

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText =
      this.getDisplayNumber(this.currentOperand)
    if (this.operation != null) {
      this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText =
        `${this.getDisplayNumber(this.previousOperand)} ${this.operation}`
    } else {
      this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = ''
    }
  }
}


const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]')
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]')
const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]')
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')

const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  })
})

operationButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  })
})

equalsButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  calculator.compute()
  calculator.updateDisplay()
})

allClearButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  calculator.clear()
  calculator.updateDisplay()
})

deleteButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
  calculator.delete()
  calculator.updateDisplay()
})

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  let patternForNumbers = /[0-9]/g;
  let patternForOperators = /[+\-*\/]/g
  if (event.key.match(patternForNumbers)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.appendNumber(event.key)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  }
  if (event.key === '.') {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.appendNumber(event.key)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  }
  if (event.key.match(patternForOperators)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.chooseOperation(event.key)
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  }
  if (event.key === 'Enter' || event.key === '=') {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.compute()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  }
  if (event.key === "Backspace") {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.delete()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  }
  if (event.key == 'Delete') {
    event.preventDefault();
    calculator.clear()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
  }

});
```

functions.py :

```
#All functions listed here

import math

# double input functions below

def add(a, b):
    return a+b

def subt(a, b):
    return a-b

def multi(a, b):
    return a*b

def divi(a, b):
    return a/b

def floDivi(a, b):
    return a//b

def remDivi(a, b):
    return a%b    

def power(a, b):
    return math.pow(a, b)

def log(a, b):
    return math.log(a,[b])

# single input functions below

def sqrt(a):
    return math.sqrt(a)

def cbrt(a):
    return a**(1./3)

# trigonometry related functions below

def rad(a):
    return math.radians(a)

def deg(a):
    return math.degrees(a)

def cos(a):
    return math.cos(a)

def sin(a):
    return math.sin(a)

def tan(a):
    return math.tan(a)

def sec(a):
    return (1/math.cos(a))

def cosec(a):
    return (1/math.sin(a))

def cot(a):
    return (1/math.tan(a))

# miscellaneous functions

def ceil(a):
    return math.ceil(a)

def floor(a):
    return math.ceil(a)

def abso(a):
    return math.fabs(a)

def facto(a):
    return math.factorial(a)
```

[The current status and how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IPKS.png)

I am not getting any output and no button is working anymore as soon as I replaced the javascript functions in script.js with imported functions from functions.py
If possible please suggest a solution that involves python, I have to include python since it is for a school project. Hopefully we can work out a solution fast.

Comment: How are you able to load a Python script into the browser?

Comment: Import your python file into the html file to use it there or in the javascript file to use its things. Im using it for functions cuz its a school project idk why its not working

Comment: I tried googling using Python scripts from the browser, the answers I found required loading a third-party library like Brython.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you running this all on the client-side? Like @Barmar said, Python doesn't run natively in browsers without an extra dependency.

Comment: Yes i am running it all client side

Comment: I dont see how to use Brython for my issue and i cant find anything similar to what i need according to what you are suggesting

Answer (score 1):

As I undrstood, your problem is that you have some code in python that you want to run in browser on client-side.

I think that the best solution here would be just to rewrite your python code in js. You could do it manually or use some python to javascript converter like [this](https://extendsclass.com/python-to-javascript.html).

You might also be intrested in this [js global Math object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math).